# Jenkins: Facing issue Insert choice parameters in Goals and options

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to run the Jenkins job which is as below, which is absolutly working fine:

```
clean verify -Denvironment=default -Dtags="type:NL" -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome -Dorganization=$organization -Dit.test=TC09_DBG_Debug_Features
```

For `-Dtags="type:NL"`, with 'NL', i am having three different tags SE,DE and DEMO. Which is as below:

1. `-Dtags="type:NL"`
2. `-Dtags="type:SE"`
3. `-Dtags="type:DE"`
4. `-Dtags="type:DEMO"`

I decided to go with **'Choice parameters'** in Jenkins having **NL,SE,DE and DEMO** as choices and name as 'Tenant'.

The problem i am facing is how to put choice parameters in **Goals and options**.

[image]

I tried

```
clean verify -Denvironment=default -Dtags= "-DpropertyName="$Tenant"" -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome -Dorganization=$organization -Dit.test=TC09_DBG_Debug_Features
```

but no help. Where am i going wrong. Thanks for help and try in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution:

```
clean verify -Denvironment=default -Dtags="$Tenant" -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome -Dorganization=$organization -Dit.test=TC09_DBG_Debug_Features
```